# Collection doesn't exist while trying to send data to two tables in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-collection

I was trying to add categories to products. I want to do it with a couple of tables between items and categories. I made a function in my controller to send it to the database. However, when I want to send it, I get the following error, and I don't know I can fix it.

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::does not exist

**Controller**

```
public function store(ItemsValidatorRequest $request)
{
    $items_id = Item::select('items_id')->latest()->get();
    $item = Item::find($items_id);
    $item->categories()->attach($request->categories);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$items_id` would be an array of ids, so the `Item::find($items_id)` would return `collection` of Items that each Item has categories. So try to use [`each` higher order messages](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages):

```
$items_id = Item::select('items_id')->latest()->get();
$items = Item::find($items_id);
$items->each->categories()->attach($request->categories);
```

or simply:

```
$items = Item::latest()->get();
$items->each->categories()->attach($request->categories);
```

Comment: hi @Hafez Divandari. I have a question. I putted the code in but now I get the same error for attach. Is there a way I can fix that as well?

Comment: @Timmie282 you have a typo in your code, change `BelongsToMany` to `belongsToMany`.

Comment: already did that and didn't fixed the error. Still got the error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::attach does not exist.

Comment: @Timmie282 it shouldn't happen, are you sure you have used `each->categories()->attach` with parentheses and not `each->categories->attach` ?

Comment: I currently have $items->each->categories()->attach($request->categories). So I got it but I get the error

Comment: @Timmie282 please make sure that the error is coming from this line, try to comment it out and see that if the error is gone or not!

Comment: if i comment it out the code works normaly. So I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function store(ItemsValidatorRequest $request)
{
    // Here the $items_id will be a collection of ids not a single one
    $items_id = Item::select('items_id')->latest()->get();

    //Here the $item will be a collection of Item records
    //Since you are passing an array/collection of id to the find
    $item = Item::find($items_id);

    //This will error out as collection of Item records do not have categories relation/method on it
    $item->categories()->attach($request->categories);
}
```

So try this

```php
public function store(ItemsValidatorRequest $request)
{
    $items_id = Item::select('items_id')->latest()->first();
    $item = Item::findOrFail($items_id);
    $item->categories()->attach($request->categories);
}
```